# Promised DynamoDB doesn't save all the items cycled in a Promise.map

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, promise, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I've a problem saving multiple items in DynamoDB. My code is structured like this:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

//config promise environment for AWS SDK
AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(require("bluebird"));
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "*",
    secretAccessKey: "*",
    region: 'eu-west-1'
});

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var arrayReading = []; //array of element we are going to save
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { //filling the array
    var reading = {
        "device": null,
        "timestamp": new Date().toISOString(),
        "installation": "1",
        "values": []
    };
    console.log("creation: DEV" + i);
    reading.device = "DEV" + i;
    arrayReading.push(reading);
}
console.log(arrayReading.length);
Promise.map(arrayReading, function (reading) {
    console.log("saving device", reading.device);
    var params = {
        "TableName": "readings-test",
        "Item": reading
    };

    return dynamodb.put(params).promise() //saving
        .catch(function (err, data) {
            console.log("Error:",err);
        });
}).then(function () {
    console.log("done")
});
```

The console log output i get is like this:

```
creation: DEV0
[...]
creation: DEV9
10
saving device DEV0
[...]
saving device DEV9
done
```

So I'm assuming all elements are saved. Instead, when I go to check in my DynamoDB table I see that only a random subset of my elements (3 to 6) has been saved.

What am I doing wrong? I tried rising the write/read capacity of my table but that didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the primary/sort key configuration.

My primary key was the installation and the sort key the timestamp. This caused a cluster of quick async writings have the same timestamp, overwriting the previous entry.